# terminaltables asciitables and encoding

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8, ascii

So I am trying to figure out how to properly encode the `.table` function in terminaltables but so far no luck.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from terminaltables import AsciiTable


html = """<a href="#" class="link" title="Some title B">
                Some text with åäö</a>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
test = soup.find('a').get_text(strip=True).encode('utf-8')
test_list = [test]
test_table = AsciiTable(test_list)

print test_list
print test
print test_table.table
```

This will print

```
['Some text with \xc3\xa5\xc3\xa4\xc3\xb6']
Some text with åäö
```

And the traceback for the `test_table.table`

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: unexpected end of data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for asciitable](https://robpol86.github.io/terminaltables/asciitable.html) states that the argument to `AsciiData` should be a list of list of strings.

Changing your definition of `test_list` to `test_list = [[test]]` prints out a table for me.

Dropping the `encode('utf-8')` from the definition of `test` makes it show up nicely on my terminal.